# Bessel-like integral with sinc

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I'm looking for a closed-form solution of the following integral in terms of standard functions such as sine, cosine, exponential, etc, as well as special functions such as Bessel functions:

$$
 \int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{sinc}(y/a) e^{ix\cos y} dy 
$$
where here $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \sin(\pi x)/(\pi x)$.

I am aware that if there was no $\operatorname{sinc}$ factor, the integral would reduce to:
$$
 \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ix\cos y} dy  = 2\pi J_0(x)
$$

I've tried using a Maclaurin series expansion for $\operatorname{sinc}$:
$$
\operatorname{sinc}(x) \approx 1-\frac{(\pi x)^2}{3!}+\frac{(\pi x)^4}{5!}-\ldots
$$
but this requires a large number of terms, and I am unsure how to compute the integrals that result (with coefficients factored outside the integral):
$$
 \int_0^{2\pi} y^n e^{ix\cos y} dy, \quad n\in \{2, 4, 6, \ldots\}
$$

Are either of these integrals (the one with the $\operatorname{sinc}$ factor or the one with the $y^n$ factor) integrals with known solutions, and if not, can you suggest a possible closed-form solution method?

Comment: One way to obtain the easy integral is via the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobi-AngerExpansion.html); that might provide an angle of attack for the sinc version as well.

Comment: By developing both $\text{sinc}$ and $e^{ix\cos y}$ into their Fourier cosine series we get that the integral is a fast-converging series whose terms are given by a product between a Bessel function and a sine integral.